# i am trying to implement this sorting but i dont seems to get arround it

Tags: next.js

i AM trying to implement this function to pass the value to the fetch product

```
 <ListBox
          options={[
            { name: 'text-lowest-price', value: 'lowest' },
            { name: 'text-highest-price', value: 'highest' },
            { name: 'text-new-arrival', value: 'new-arrival' },
            { name: 'text-most-order', value: 'most-order' },
          ]}
        />
```

please if anyone have done something like this i realy need some help i have to present something tomorrow

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<Option>(currentSelectedItem);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedItem(currentSelectedItem);
  }, [currentSelectedItem]);
  function handleItemClick(values: Option) {
    setSelectedItem(values);
    const { sort_by, ...restQuery } = query;
    router.push(
      {
        pathname,
        query: {
          ...restQuery,
          ...(values.value !== options[0].value
            ? { sort_by: values.value }
            : {}),
        },
      },
      undefined,
      { scroll: false }
    );
  }
```